# TixComboBox subwidget not selecting/being set to specified value on first use

Tags: python, tkinter, tix

I have a `TixExFileSelectDialog` that is associated with several `Entry` objects in my program; the dialog is dynamically configured so that the selected file matches the text in the `Entry` the dialog is being used for. However, the first time the dialog is opened, regardless of which `Entry` is used, it only displays the pattern string, even when the `Entry` already has a default value. However, if I cancel out of the dialog and then reopen it, it displays the proper string. This happens when I set any combination of the combo box's `selection` and `value` options (one, the other, and both), as well as when I set the combo box's `variable` option to a `StringVar`. Is there something I'm missing in how `TixComboBox`s function?

The code I'm currently using (with some reformatting/etc. for posting):

```
from tkinter.tix import *

opts = {'path': 'C:\\'}

class ImportGUI(Frame):
    def _setfsd(self, directory='', pattern='*.xls', variable='', selection=None):
        "Reconfigures the ExFileSelectDialog to enable reusability."
        self.fsd.fsbox.config(directory=directory or opts['path'], # can't use opts['path'] as a default argument, because it could change.
                              pattern=pattern)

        self.fsd.fsbox.file['variable'] = variable

        if not variable:
            self.fsd.fsbox.file['value'] = selection or pattern # Defaults to the pattern, which is the behavior of a fresh ExFileSelectionBox.
        elif selection is not None:   # variable exists, but setting selection manually as well
            self.fsd.fsbox.file['value'] = selection

    def _selectdatafile(self):
        self._setfsd(selection='apple1.xls')
        self.fsd.popup()

    def _selectcodefile(self):
        self._setfsd(selection='apple2.xls')
        self.fsd.popup()

    def createWidgets(self):
        self.fsd = ExFileSelectDialog(self.master) # a top-level widget, so giving it the default root as master

        self.dfrow = Frame(self)
        self.cfrow = Frame(self)

        self.dfentry = Entry(self.dfrow)
        self.dfentry.pack(side='left')
        self.cfentry = Entry(self.cfrow)
        self.cfentry.pack(side='left')

        self.dfbtn = Button(self.dfrow, text='...', command=self._selectdatafile)
        self.dfbtn.pack(side='left')
        self.cfbtn = Button(self.cfrow, text='...', command=self._selectcodefile)
        self.cfbtn.pack(side='left')

        self.dfrow.pack()
        self.cfrow.pack()
        self.pack()

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master.tk.eval('package require Tix')
        self.createWidgets()

if __name__ == '__main__': # for testing
    gui = ImportGUI()
    gui.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, I had no need to do any of this in the first place because I can just use `askopenfilename()` from [`tkinter.filedialog`](http://tkinter.unpythonic.net/wiki/tkFileDialog) to get exactly the functionality I desire, using the look-and-feel of the current OS. So much for Tix.

(Well, it wasn't *exactly* what I wanted, as the look was still a bit dated on Windows, but it was close enough. [IDLE seems to use it too, for that matter.])